# The minimum possible value of $\,\,|w|^2+|w-3|^2+|w-6i|^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am stuck on the following problem :

> What is the minimum possible value of $\,\,|w|^2+|w-3|^2+|w-6i|^2\,\,,w \in \Bbb C,i=\sqrt{-1}\,\,$?
>
> The options are $\,\,15,45,20,30.$

I have no idea how to tackle it effectively. Some detailed explanation will be of great help.

Comment: With the help of @André Nicolas , the answer is 30.

Comment: yes. I  have  got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $w=x+iy$, where $x$ and $y$ are real. Then the expression we are looking at is 
$$x^2+y^2 +(x-3)^2+y^2 +x^2+(y-6)^2.$$
Expand, and complete the squares. I expect that part will give you no trouble. If it does, I can show in detail how to finish. We will get lucky and be able to divide by $3$, making the arithmetic simpler.

Comment: @learner: Good, a start was enough.

Comment: I think I have got it. $x^2+y^2+(x−3)^2+y^2+x^2+(y−6)^2=3[(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2+10]$ and so min. value will be obtained at $x=1,y=2$ and it will be $3 \times 10=30.$ Am I right?

Comment: I get the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=x+ i y$ and compute:

$f((x,y)) = x^2+y^2+(x-3)^2+y^2+x^2+(y-6)^2 = 3(y^2-4y+x^2-2x+15)$

$f$ is a strictly convex quadratic (in fact it is separable, so we can minimize $x,y$ independently), so has a unique minimum.
Since $Df((x,y)) = 6(x-1,y-2)$, we see that the minimum occurs at $(1,2)$. Substitute these values to get the result.